# How to change FloatingPlaceholderColor but not hint color in textinputlayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I have created TextInputLayout(OutlinedBox) with the hint. Expected to display in 3 color.

1. When placeholder is focused 'Floating label' should display in color 1 (YELLOW)
2. When placeholder is unfocused 'hint' should be display in color 2(GRAY)
3. When placeholder is unfocused 'Floating label' should display in color (BLUE)

However, unfocused 'hint' and unfocused 'Floating label' always take same color as assign in placeholder(In this case color 2- Gray).

[image]

Here I have used dependancy `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_mb_text_layout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_mb_text_layout2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        style="@style/MBFormTextInputStyle"
        android:hint="label_text"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Priyanka"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Style for Hint -->
    <style name="hint_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MBFormTextInputStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/error_a`enter code here`ppearance</item>
        <item name="errorTextColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppea`enter code here`rance">@style/hint_appearance</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you ctrl+click `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"` 
It will take you to `values.xml` file. There you will see all default colors like below

```
....
....
 <color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#6B000000</color>
    <color name="mtrl_textinput_disabled_color">#1F000000</color>
    <color name="mtrl_textinput_filled_box_default_background_color">#0A000000</color>
    <color name="mtrl_textinput_focused_box_stroke_color">#00000000</color>
    <color name="mtrl_textinput_hovered_box_stroke_color">#DE000000</color>
....
....
```

Pick suitable color you want to change and override it in `colors.xml` file. That's all